# cómo se activa mysqlnd en servidor, editando php.ini

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo un error en:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()
```

Mi código es

```
$conexion = new mysqli('localhost','','','');
if (mysqli_connect_error()) { echo mysqli_connect_error(); exit; }
$q = "%$_POST[q]%";

$consulta= $conexion->prepare("SELECT ar.Titulo_Articulo, ar.Id_Articulo, r.Id_Revista FROM articulos as ar INNER JOIN revista as r on r.Id_Revista = ar.Id_Revista where ar.pdf LIKE ?");

$consulta->bind_param('s', $q);


$consulta->execute();
$res = $consulta->get_result();


if($conexion->affected_rows>0)

{
    while($fila=$res->fetch_array())
        {



echo '<a href="autenticacion.php?id='.$fila["Id_Revista"].'&articulo='.$fila["Id_Articulo"].'" width="50%" class="sugerencias" onclick="myFunction2('.utf8_encode($fila["Titulo_Articulo"]).')"><br>'.utf8_encode($fila['Titulo_Articulo']).'</a>';

        }
}
else
{
    echo '<b>No hay sugerencias</b>';
}
$consulta->close();
$conexion->close();
```

estoy en mi servidor, nunca realice pruebas locales

si ya habia leido eso de la pregunta en stack

MySQL Native Driver Only ¶

Available only with mysqlnd.

pero no se como activar el driver, me hablan de unos comandos pero donde entro o que onda :S

Hola a todos actualizo el post ya se encuentra solucionado el error era porque yo tenia la versión 5.3 y ese error es a a partir de la versión 5.4, he actualizado a la versión más reciente y trabaja sin problemas.

Comment: En que entorno estas desarrollando, Windows o Linux??

Comment: Mira http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result

Comment: si ya lei eso y es con consola y no se donde van los comandos por eso prefiero saber como editarlo en php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Para activar o desactivar extensiones, debes abrir el archivo php.ini y buscar la extensión que quieres activar.

Una vez la encuentres tan solo debes eliminar el símbolo # de delante, grabar el archivo y reiniciar apache.

Para desactivar una extensión vuelve a poner delante el símbolo # grabar el archivo y reiniciar apache.